# How to use Java Timer in Android?

Tags: java, android, timer

My program with Timer was working in Java but not working in Android. Android did not accept ActionListener, ActionEvent or timer.start(), timer.stop(). What should I do? Thanks a lot for any help!

```
   private Timer timer;

    timer = new Timer(2 * 1000, new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(condition == true) {
            // do my job when it's true
                                   }
            else{
            timer.stop(); //stop it
                 }
                                                 }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);//auto restarts the timer after it triggers
```

Comment: Which Timer class do you think you're using? java.util.Timer? javax.swing.Timer? java.util.Timer doesn't take an ActionListener in the constructor...

Comment: i do import javax.swing.Timer;

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [`java.util.Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) class instead of the `javax.swing.Timer` class you were using before.

Therefore you must construct the timer with a [`java.util.TimerTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) instead of an ActionListener.

Also you can't repeatedly stop and start this kind of timer. You can only [`cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()) it, after which it cannot be reused, so you must create a new Timer for each time you want to start one.